# Typing notification to user in dialogflow chatbot

Tags: node.js, firebase, dialogflow-es

I have developed a chatbot using dialogflow and hosted my webhook api to firebase cloud. I have integrated this bot to MS Team and Skype where I am able to access the bot from both channels. I have a requirement that I have to show "user typing..." notification to users in the chat window similar to session.sendTyping() having in MSBot. Do we have similar functionality using webhook option? 
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a feature that is built into Dialogflow. If you want to add this, you'll need to use another system to store the state of the focus and receive it on other devices. This could be accomplished through storing the boolean state in Firebase's database, for example.